# javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ',' in key part of property

Tags: spring-boot, ubuntu

When i run my springboot application via intelij idea with ubundu machine throwing error like below
but windows machine working fine ...
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\ / ***'* __ _ *(*)* __  __ _ \ \ \ 

( ( )_*_ | '_ | '*| | '* / *` | \ \ \ 

\/  __*)| |*)| | | | | || (*| |  ) ) ) )
'  |****| .__|*| |*|*| |*_*, | / / / /
=========|*|==============|***/=/*/*/*/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.4)

2023-12-01 18:31:04.841  INFO 255813 --- [           main] com.vismaya.ib.user.UserApplication      : Starting UserApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 11.0.20.1 on linges-Vostro-15-3568 with PID 255813 (/home/linges/Vismaya/internet-banking-backend/IB_Backend_applications/user/target/user-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by linges in /home/linges/Vismaya/internet-banking-backend/IB_Backend_applications/user/target)
2023-12-01 18:31:04.845  INFO 255813 --- [           main] com.vismaya.ib.user.UserApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-12-01 18:31:06.665  INFO 255813 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-12-01 18:31:06.949  INFO 255813 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 261 ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-12-01 18:31:07.710  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=f0304fe5-8cd4-3349-aef6-6cb5f27710bc
2023-12-01 18:31:08.622  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8082 (http)
2023-12-01 18:31:08.623  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.31] using APR version [1.7.0].
2023-12-01 18:31:08.624  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
2023-12-01 18:31:08.624  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
2023-12-01 18:31:08.629  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022]
2023-12-01 18:31:08.646  INFO 255813 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-12-01 18:31:08.646  INFO 255813 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2023-12-01 18:31:08.665  WARN 255813 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase     : Failed to register object [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].TomcatEmbeddedContext[/user/api/v1Select p.permission_id, p.name from permission p where permission_id IN (]] with name [Tomcat:j2eeType=WebModule,name=//localhost/user/api/v1Select p.permission_id, p.name from permission p where permission_id IN (,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none] during component initialisation

javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ',' in key part of property
at java.management/javax.management.ObjectName.construct(ObjectName.java:554) ~[na:na]
at java.management/javax.management.ObjectName.(ObjectName.java:1406) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.register(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:155) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase.initInternal(LifecycleMBeanBase.java:57) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.initInternal(ContainerBase.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.initInternal(StandardContext.java:6290) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]
at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:479) ~[spring-boot-2.7.4.jar!/:2.7.4]

When i run my springboot application via intelij idea with ubundu machine throwing error like below
but windows machine working fine ...

Comment: Please format the stacktrace so it is more readable. Also, as the error suggests, you might have a special character in your property name. Please check your application.yml or application.properties for any special characters in the key of your properties.